# WebRTC on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, screensharing

I would like to create a simple webRTC application (screen sharing) where one end of the peer-to-peer connection is pi and the other is a chrome on Mac OSX. The pi side of the connection only needs to show the video stream and not share. Looks like chromium on pi or other browsers dont support webRTC. Any other thoughts or solutions to this problem?

Comment: I know that people(including me) have successfully used Gstreamer along with [the Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) to create a peerconnection to stream to and from a raspi.

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi 1 or 2? I did some primitive tests using a Pi 1 B+ and I could install WebRTC-able browsers and establish peer connections. However, it was impractical due to performance issues.

Comment: I am using raspberry pi1. which browser did you install and do you have pointers?

Answer (score 1):

For WebRTC for Raspberry Pi 2 there is [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/). It allows you to stream live Audio & Video from the Rpi to any browser.

Comment: It's right and it works well, however it could be nice that you improve the answer explaining how to capture the screen, the need webrtc plugins....

Comment: in theory the xscreen driver for uv4l and the webrtc plugin can do the screen sharing